# How to make tensorflow detect my text files?

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-processing

I use the tensorflow function [text_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text_dataset_from_directory) that takes text files and load them into Tensorflow datasets. I use the same structure of folders as mentioned by Tensorflow but the function **does not detect** the text files.

Here's the code I run:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(directory='data/train', batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.2,subset='training', seed=seed,label_mode='binary',labels=[0,1])
```

my folders look like this: data > train > pos.txt and neg.txt
It gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected the lengths of `labels` to match the number of files in the target directory. len(labels) is 2 while we found 0 files in data/train.
```

I also tried with a different structure like data> train> pos > pos.txt and train>neg>neg.txt but still it told me that there were no files found.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: it works for me with `data/train/0/pos.txt` and `data/train/1/neg.txt` - at least gives different error because I have empty files - but it shows `Found 2 files belonging to 2 classes.`

Comment: it works for me also with `data/train/pos/pos.txt` and `data/train/neg/neg.txt`

Comment: maybe first check `os.getcwd()` and `os.listdir()` to see if you work with correct folder `data/train`

Comment: I created another folder with named "data_tf" with `train/0/pos.txt` and `train/1/neg.txt` inside of it. It gives the following error: `ValueError: No text files found. ` But it display this: `Found 2 files belonging to 2 classes. Using 2 files for training.`. I checked and `os.getcwd()` gives me the folder containing data_df

Comment: so now you have different problem - and you should create new question on new page. Now you have to ask how to create correct files for tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll do it asap

Comment: You can find the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970090/how-to-create-correct-text-files-for-tensorflow

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Make sure the parameters have a valid value, in my case, it was the "validation_split" causing issues. Make sure the number of files is divisible with the validation_split. For example, 2 files cant have a validation_split=0.2, but a value of validation_split=0.5 would be accepted.

Comment: I'm sorry but validation_split has got nothing to do with number of files but rather with the number of records in a dataset. Obviously, if you provide a path to nonexistent files, you will get an Exception, which in OP's post is quite clear and not in need of any speciation nor interpretation, to begin with.

Comment: Haha, I made a typo above. Instead of "speciation" I meant "speculation"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).