# How to create correct text files for tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-processing

Tensorflow cannot find the text files created from a dataframe. The code below gives me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d5b632e1e805> in <module>
      2 seed = 123
      3 
----> 4 train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(directory='data_tf/train', batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.2,subset='training', seed=seed,label_mode='binary',labels=[0,1])
      5 
      6 val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(directory='data_tf/train', batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.2,subset='validation', seed=seed,labels=[0,1],label_mode='binary')

~/my_repo//venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/text_dataset.py in text_dataset_from_directory(directory, labels, label_mode, class_names, batch_size, max_length, shuffle, seed, validation_split, subset, follow_links)
    155       file_paths, labels, validation_split, subset)
    156   if not file_paths:
--> 157     raise ValueError('No text files found.')
    158 
    159   dataset = paths_and_labels_to_dataset(

ValueError: No text files found.
```

but also displays this before crashing `Found 2 files belonging to 2 classes. Using 2 files for training.`

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(directory='data_tf/train', batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.2,subset='training', seed=seed,label_mode='binary',labels=[0,1])`
```

The folder structure is correct and is the following:
data_tf > train > 0 > neg.txt / data_tf > train > 1 > pos.txt

I created the text files using `to_csv()` function : `pos_df.to_csv(r'data_tf/train/1/pos.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')`.

Should I created the text files with another method so it is accepted by tensorflow? Thanks.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You need minimum two text files in each directory, else it won't work.

[image]